# Black screen after unlock screen

Tags: release-juno, display, system, elementary-project

Frequently I need to lock my screen using `Super+L`, but when I put my password to unlock, the system presents a black screen for over 10 seconds. After that all things are ok, but this black screen is the worst.

```
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Release:    5.0
Codename:   juno
```

Comment: Its a very old bug, i really want it to be fixed, i need to change to another lock screen because of this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can't take away the black screen entirely, but increasing the graphics memory will reduce the time the black screen stays on your monitor.

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me on Odin yesterday. (it used to happen from time to time on Hera).
So that bug is still around.

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed, black screen with blinking is still present.

my solution is press ctrl+alt+F1 and write

```
sudo systemctl restart display-manager
```

or

```
sudo reboot
```